# Want to add characters to every element of a data frame

Tags: r, string

I have a data frame of strings as below and would like to add the string "Market" to each of the elements of the data frame. Is there a function that would allow me to do this easily without having to use a for loop?

```
                                 V1
1 PUBLIC_DISPATCHSCADA_20141221.zip
2 PUBLIC_DISPATCHSCADA_20141222.zip
3 PUBLIC_DISPATCHSCADA_20141223.zip
4 PUBLIC_DISPATCHSCADA_20141224.zip
5 PUBLIC_DISPATCHSCADA_20141225.zip
6 PUBLIC_DISPATCHSCADA_20141226.zip
```

Comment: Where do you want to add? Before? After? Middle?

Comment: Seriously? +3?  Wow.  This question is amazingly unclear.  Whoever upvoted this should be ashamed of themselves.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We can use `paste` and specify the delimiter.  In this case, I am using `_` and `paste`ing the "Market" at the beginning of the string.

```
df1$V1 <- paste("Market", df1$V1, sep="_")
```

If we need to do this for each column

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) paste("Market", x, sep="_"))
```

Comment: you can also use str_c from stringr package

https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2010-2/RJournal_2010-2_Wickham.pdf

Comment: @AjayOhri `sprintf` is also a possible flexible option.